# Finding a function $f$ such that $fg(t) = g(t)^f$ for any $g(t)$

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I have a problem in my calculation that could be solved in there is some function, $f$, s.t. for any $g(t)$,
\begin{gather}
   f\cdot g(t) = g(t)^f.
\end{gather}
I am able to simplify down to $f^{1/(f-1)} = g(t)$, however I would like to find the function $f$ not $g(t)$. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(t)=1$ for all $t$ works.

Comment: @Carla_ Make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a solution using the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which by definition is such that $W(\color{Green}{x}e^{\color{Green}{x}}) =\color{Green}{x}$:

\begin{align}
fg = g^{f} &\implies f g^{-f} = \frac{1}{g}\\
&\implies \color{purple}{-\ln(g)} f g^{-f} = \frac{\color{purple}{-\ln(g)} }{g}\\
&\implies \color{Green}{-\ln(g)f}  e^{\color{Green}{-\ln(g)f}} = \frac{-\ln(g)}{g}\\
&\implies \color{Green}{-\ln(g)f} = W\left(\frac{-\ln(g)}{g}\right)\\
&\implies  \boxed{f(t) = -\frac{1}{\ln(g)}W\left(\frac{-\ln(g)}{g}\right)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is an equation of the type $x^{f(x)} = g(x)$. Such an equation has no trivial solution , and is variant on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

(It can be rearranged to give $f(x) = \frac{\log(g(x))}{\log(x)}$)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate a non-trivial solution?

Comment: @JehanDastoor Well, you have $f(x) = \frac{\log(g(x))}{\log(x)}$, which may be approximated through certain numerical methods, or calculated exactly depending on $g(x)$. For example, if $g(x) = x$, you simply have $f(x) = 1$. $g(x) = x^{n}$ gives $f(x) = n$